# Add a cell value to Right Click Menu in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to add a cell value to the right click menu in Excel (version 2010)? In the example, I would like to display cell value B1 on Sheet1. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do that? If you just want a quick way to check the value, use the Watch window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, a good reference can be found here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469862(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469862%28v=office.14%29.aspx)